# Translate a point's position on 1 image to another

Tags: python, opencv

I have 2 `np.zeros` images. 1 image is fixed i.e `100 x 100`, the other can be `m x n`. Given I have the `coordinates` of a `point` on the `m x n` image, i want to translate the position of the point on the 1st `100 x 100` image.

Comment: Please show your code, where this point is and how it maps to the second image.

Comment: Actually, there isn't much code right now. All I need is that math function that takes dimensions of both images, takes the coordinates of the point and returns back the coordinates that translate the position of the point on the static image.

Comment: Just divide by the size to get the position as a floating point number between 0 and 1. Then multiply by 100, et voila, your point now has coordinates between 0 and 100. `x, y = int(100*x/w), int(100*y/h)`

Comment: @alkasm So let's say we have a `(600, 800)` image. There is a point `(150, 150)` on this image. Now let's say we have a `(500, 500)` image. I want to find out the coordinates of the point on the second image.

Comment: The point is 1/4 of the way across the 600px image so it will be 1/4 of the way across the 500px image, i.e. at 125px across.

Comment: @IbtihajTahir then it's `x, y = int(500*150/800), int(500*150/600)`. Bad choice to use the same x, y, and w, h of new image in this case, since it's ambiguous :P but my first comment should be good. Just replace the two 100s with `new_w` and `new_h` respectively. I.e., in general: `x, y = int(new_w * x / old_w), int(new_h * y / old_h)`

Comment: @alkasm Your solution works fine. Thanks. Put that in answer

Comment: Note that any point in the original image could be blurred across multiple pixels in the output image as a result of interpolation and even if you use *"nearest neighbour"* resizing, an input pixel may or may not appear at exactly the place you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe yourquestion can be solved by affine transformation. for more detail answer,give an example. [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d61/tutorial_warp_affine.html),python example : [link](https://www.learnopencv.com/warp-one-triangle-to-another-using-opencv-c-python/)
 and related question : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37168115/how-to-find-corresponding-points-in-two-images)